# Can't npm install or use git after upgrading to MacOS Mohave 10.14.4 (18E226)

Tags: git, macos, curl, npm, homebrew

This works for a while after restart, but then I'm hit with the same error:

`curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to ssl.icu-project.org:443`

and `request failed ... read ECONNRESET`

This happens for brew, git, and npm.

Here's my brew config:

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 2.1.1
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: b4f73e61649fcfc5aaa779c311e2514619ce01e7
Last commit: 3 weeks ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: 422ef941c0a2b69e9e1ab93612cfbb2ead581bf6
Core tap last commit: 3 days ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_LOGS: /Users/home/Library/Logs/Homebrew
CPU: octa-core 64-bit haswell
Homebrew Ruby: 2.3.7 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby
Clang: 10.0 build 1001
Git: 2.21.0 => /usr/local/bin/git
Curl: 7.54.0 => /usr/bin/curl
macOS: 10.14.4-x86_64
CLT: 10.2.0.0.1.1552586384
Xcode: N/A
CLT headers: 10.2.0.0.1.1552586384
```

Things I have tried:

- reinstalling brew, curl, git, node, etc.
- `export HOMEBREW_FORCE_BREWED_CURL=1`
- There is no proxy or proxy settings present
- `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`

This error forces me to restart every couple of hours and is frustrating when I'm working. This only started to happen since I upgraded to MacOS Mojave, I would assume it's a problem with curl - but I can't fix it.

Comment: Have you installed Xcode command line tools?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes, I have it installed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lay with my antivirus software. More specifically: **Kaspersky**.

After reinstallation the problem no longer persisted. Posting this incase it helps anyone else in the future.

Comment: Good catch there